# Getting error trying to read a json file with babel/register module

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, babeljs, nconf

this is my config file:

```
import nconf from "nconf";
import path from "path";

nconf.argv()
    .env()
    .file({
        file: path.join(
                __dirname,
                `manifest.${process.env['NODE_ENV'] || 'development'}.json`
            )
    });

var manifest = {
    server: nconf.get('server'),
    connections: nconf.get('connections'),
    plugins: nconf.get('plugins')
};

export default manifest;
```

and this is the config file

```
{
    "server": {},
    "connections": [
        {
            "port": 3000,
            "labels": ["api"]
        }
    ],
    "plugins": [
        {
            "vision": {},
            "visionary": {
                "engines": {
                    "jsx": "hapi-react-views"
                },
                "relativeTo": __dirname,
                "path": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

unfortunately I get the following error:

```
throw new Error("Error parsing your configuration file: [" + self.file +
            ^
Error: Error parsing your configuration file: [/Users/mazzy/vagrant-devbox/hapi-react-es6/server/config/manifest.development.json]: Unexpected token _
    at [object Object].File.loadSync (/Users/mazzy/vagrant-devbox/hapi-react-es6/node_modules/nconf/lib/nconf/stores/file.js:14
```

Comment: `__dirname` is not valid JSON. Wrapping that in a string, then eval-ing it in your JS could work, or just put the desired path.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is here:

```
"relativeTo": __dirname,
```

nconf is assuming your config file is JSON, but this isn't valid JSON.

If you need JavaScript in your config file, one option is to `require` (or `import`) it and then use `.defaults` instead of `.file` (you'll probably want to change the filename from `.json` to `.js` to make it clear that it's JavaScript, not JSON):

```
import nconf from "nconf";
import path from "path";
import config from `./manifest.${process.env['NODE_ENV'] || 'development'}`;

nconf.argv()
    .env()
    .defaults(config);

// ...
```

I haven't tested this, but hopefully it helps.